# Stop Timer Task if the task runs in another class

Tags: java, timer

I have a class Sample that calls a timer task in another class how can I stop the timer after executing the timer twice? This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Sample extends Someotherclass
public static void main()
{
    public void initiate() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Timer(), 0, 10000);
    }
}
```

and

```
class Timer extends TimerTask {
    private static int count = 0;
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        count++;
        if(count>1)
        {
            //stop the timer schedule
            // timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`timer.cancel()` will terminates the timer, but started task will keep running.
The `TimerTask.cancel()` API does NOT work if the task is started.
Why don't you just `return;` to exit `run()` method?

### Update

The solution to stop `java.util.Timer` from instance of `TimerTask` is throw `RuntimeException` except `java.lang.InterruptedException` (This type is catched by `TimerThread.mainLoop()`)

Comment: Are you talk about the instance of `java.util.Timer`? or the instance of `java.util.TimerTask`? I didn't notice `class Timer extends TimerTask` in your question. It make me confused without package name...

Comment: I am trying to stop it via the instance of timer task

Comment: I just update the answer, it should work for your case too.